# Delete time from video project

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to delete the frames between 100 and 200 from my project and have all strips automatically shift to compensate (thus, pre-delete frame 200 automatically would become post-delete frame 101 without having to manually drag any strips). This is a standard feature in audio workstations I've used; e.g. not wanting the audio between minute 1:00 and 2:00 and using a command to delete that time, automatically shifting all tracks to the start point of deletion.

How can I do this in Blender? (Can I?)

Comment: Use blenders VSE, hit shift k where at frame 100, and at frame 200. Delete frames between 99-201. Then slide over the video, G to the start of the second one. Then slide them both back to frame one. Check micheal myers youtube videos on blenders vse for more information

Comment: @SammySwanson - you should post that as an answer. Maybe also add a couple of screenshots.

Comment: What you search for is called Ripple Delete. Alternatively if you'd like to perform such deletions on more complex scenes just use Nested Scene strips.

Comment: I also recommend [video #10](https://youtu.be/rl6FmFLkARI) from Mikeycal Myers. It shows you how to box select strips and then move them quickly to the first empty frame.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. It's fairly easy once you know how.

1. Go to the frame you want to start on. In your case, 100.[image: Changing time to 100]
2. First select the whole video. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, to hard cut. Now you should have two videos and/or audio(cutting the video cuts the audio too)[image: Cut timeline].
3. Then do the same as number one but to last frame you want to cut out. (200)
4. Simply select the middle video and audio, and press <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd>[image: yep]
5. Finally select the last strip of video and audio and slide over to the first using <kbd>G</kbd>

#### Want More Info?

Check out Mikeycal Myers Videos on Blenders V.S.E. [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) 

For this, I would recommend video #4